# xpath and r - create a key table

Tags: xml, r, xpath, apply

I'm new to the xml package for r and new to xpath.  I have a very large xml file that I am parsing.  I wrote some code using loops that works but takes too long, so I am writing more efficient code using xpath. 
The xml looks something like this:

```
...
<person personId="1">
<personNames>
<personName nameId="1000">
<first>Joe<last>
<last>Jones<last>
</personName>
<personName nameId="1001">
<first>Joseph><first>
<last>Jones<last>
</personName>
<personName nameId="1002"
<first>The One and only Joe<first>
</personName>
</personNames>
</person>
...
```

Some people have one name, some have more.  Some people have first and last names, some of just a first name or just a last name.  So, I need to be careful.

I was able to efficiently create a data frame of first and last names using xpath:

```
library(XML)
doc<-xmlTreeParse("People.xml",useInternalNodes = TRUE)
top<-xmlRoot(doc)
First<-as.character(xpathApply(top,"//person/personNames/personName/first", xmlValue))
name_id<-as.integer(xpathApply(top,"//person/personNames/personName[first]/@nameId"))
FirstNames<-data.frame(TMS_name_id=name_id,first=First)
Last<-as.character(xpathApply(top,"//person/personNames/personName/last", xmlValue))
name_id<-as.integer(xpathApply(top,"//person/personNames/personName[last]/@nameId"))
LastNames<-data.frame(name_id=name_id,last=Last)
Names<-merge(x=FirstNames,y=LastNames,by="name_id",all=TRUE)
```

My Names data frame looks good.  It has the nameId, first name, and last name of every person.  If a first or last name is missing, it is a null.  It generated in a few minutes (610K rows!).  Awesome.

The problem is associating these names with the parent personId.  I assume I need to loop through the names in my data frame, and grab the personId that has the correct nameId attribute, but I am unable to do this.  For example, the following code gives me a null result:

```
xpathSApply(top,"//person/personNames/personName[@nameId="1000"]/@personId")
```

I am expecting a result of 1.  What is the most efficient way to add a column in my data frame for personId?

Given the sample above, I want a data frame that looks like this:

```
nameId  first                  last                  personId
1000    Joe                    Jones                 1
1001    Joseph                 Jones                 1
1002    The one and only Joe   <NA>                  1
```

Comment: Could you include the final result you desire for your sample input data? I'm not sure the exact form of the output you seek.

Comment: Edit made.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Since first and last names aren't balanced, it seems like you need to be a bit more careful to match them all then just extracting them all at once.

Here's some valid test data

```
library(XML)
dd<-xmlInternalTreeParse('<people><person personId="1">
<personNames>
<personName nameId="1000"><first>Joe</first><last>Jones</last></personName>
<personName nameId="1001"><first>Joseph</first><last>Jones</last></personName>
<personName nameId="1002"><first>The One and only Joe</first></personName>
</personNames>
</person></people>')
```

Then i'll include `plyr` to make things a bit easier to collapse and also create a helper function to replace missing values with `NA`

```
library(plyr)
getXmlValue<-function(node, select) {
    x<-node[select]
      if(length(x)==1) {
        xmlValue(x[[1]])
    } else {
        NA
    }
}
```

Then I can do

```
rbind.fill(xpathApply(dd, "//person", function(x) {
    pn <- xpathApply(x, "./personNames/personName", function(x) {
        data.frame(
            nameId=xmlGetAttr(x, "nameId"), 
            first=getXmlValue(x, "first"), 
            last=getXmlValue(x,"last"))
    })
    cbind(personID=xmlGetAttr(x, "personId"), rbind.fill(pn))
}))
```

to get

```
  personID nameId                first  last
1        1   1000                  Joe Jones
2        1   1001               Joseph Jones
3        1   1002 The One and only Joe  <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a little convoluted; it was inspired by the cost of creating many single-row data.frames and then rbinding these together. I don't know whether this is more efficient or not (would be interesting to get feedback...).

In a first pass I record the 'geometry' of events as they occur

```
geom <- xpathSApply(dd, "//person|//personName|//first|//last", xmlName)
```

and in a second pass extract the names I'm interested in

```
## hack: implement XMLAttributeValue method for xmlValue
xmlValue.XMLAttributeValue <- as.character
nms <- xpathSApply(dd, 
    "//person/@personId|//personName/@nameId|//first|//last", xmlValue)
```

I then figure out how to place the names I've discovered into the correct cells in a rectangular grid

```
cols <- c(nameId="personName", first="first", last="last")
pidx = geom == "person"
ridx = cumsum(geom == "personName")
cidx <- match(geom, cols, 0)

## fill matrix with leaf nodes
m <- matrix(character(), max(ridx), max(cidx), 
            dimnames=list(NULL, names(cols)))
m[cbind(ridx, cidx)] <- nms[!pidx]

## 'expand' parent elements and bind to matrix
times <- diff(c(ridx[pidx], max(ridx)))
m <- cbind(personId=rep(nms[pidx], times), m)
```

with the end result

```
> m
     personId nameId first                  last   
[1,] "1"      "1000" "Joe"                  "Jones"
[2,] "1"      "1001" "Joseph"               "Jones"
[3,] "1"      "1002" "The One and only Joe" NA
```